# Is Maven ${project.name} ever null?

Tags: maven

I want to use `${project.name}` for resource filtering. I know that this value comes from the Maven [Model](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.3/maven-model/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/Model.html) object. But the documentation doesn't indicate if this can ever return `null`.

Is a value always assigned to `${project.name}` during resource filtering, even if the POM does not specify a `<name>`? I would prefer some authoritative reference.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can be, if you haven't defined it in the `<name/>` tag.

Why do you want to use `${project.name}`, instead of `${project.artifactId}`? You should be using the latter instead.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it would be nice to get an authoritative reference. I don't know how you could guess what I "should be" using, though, without knowing my intended goal. For example, I may want to include the project name in a filtered project or, if no name is defined, the artifact ID.